# Review the errors on this page Lightning

Tags: lightning

In the detail page of a record,if any error occurs on editing and saving(Eg: not giving value for a mandatory field) , error message is shown as below.

[image]

It is a standard edit page in lightning. I have a requirement where only the error message should be shown and not the message "Review the errors on this page".Could anyone please let me know whether it is possible to remove that line.

Comment: You can put the CSS inside static resource and add that on the page, but this is very dangerous way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is standard Salesforce functionality.